# Locus Maps - adding additional zoom levels

Tags: maps

The Locus Maps app allows downloading maps and using them offline. When selecting a map region, the zoom levels have to be selected. I've downloaded a map at a specific zoom level (23) expecting that I will be able to use lower zoom levels as well (1-22).

However - I can now only go through the map at zoom level 23, which is awkward.

Is there any way to add additional zoom levels to those maps already downloaded, without having to download the entire thing again from scratch (it's big)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After searching and searching - I don't think there's a way to do this. The only option is deleting the old map and downloading the map once again with multiple zoom levels selected.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the Locus documentation for downloading maps? Check [this document](http://docs.locusmap.eu/doku.php/manual%3amap_download).

In the end, there is a section called "Download types". There is a type called "External map", and this is what you need for this task.